# Mxnet version 1.0.0 gluon KeyError: 'shape'

Tags: python, deep-learning, mxnet

I have installed the newest mxnet version 1.0.0 from pip.
When I print the Layer's weight, it assert a KeyError: "Shape". I'm new in mxnet and everything I have followed with the mxnet official tutorial.

```
import mxnet
from mxnet import nd,gluon,autograd

net=gluon.nn.Dense(10,in_units=30)
print (net.weight)
```

The error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/docs/mxnet/mtcnn/tmp/learn_mxnet.py", line 5, in <module>
    print (net.weight)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mxnet/gluon/parameter.py", line 120, in __repr__
    return s.format(**self.__dict__)
KeyError: 'shape'
```

I think it may be the problem of the version 1.0.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check the weights, you first need to initialize them as follows:

`net.collect_params().initialize(mx.init.Xavier(), ctx=mx.cpu())`

In your case, because you didn't specify input size to layers in Net's constructor, the shape of parameters cannot be determined at this point. So, if you access `net.weight.data()` now, an exception will be raised:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mxnet-0.12.1-py2.7.egg/mxnet/gluon/parameter.py", line 389, in data
    return self._check_and_get(self._data, ctx)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mxnet-0.12.1-py2.7.egg/mxnet/gluon/parameter.py", line 189, in _check_and_get
    "nested child Blocks"%(self.name))
RuntimeError: Parameter dense0_weight has not been initialized. Note that you should initialize parameters and create Trainer with Block.collect_params() instead of Block.params because the later does not include Parameters of nested child Blocks`

You can initialize the weights as follows:

`net.collect_params().initialize(mxnet.init.Xavier(), ctx=mxnet.cpu())
print (net.weight.data())`

Answer (score 0):

You are correct about this regression on MXNet 1.0.0. It has since been [fixed](https://github.com/apache/incubator-mxnet/pull/8956) and you can install the latest beta version of MXNet for now until the next official release. To install the latest pre-release (beta) version: `pip install -U --pre mxnet`.